# ASP.NET MVC 4 Replacement for ProfileCommon?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-profiles

I am migrating a WebForms application to MVC. One of the core components of my application though is heavy use of the ProfileCommon class. My question is, how the hell do I get my existing Profile data from my database into my ASP.NET MVC controller? It looks like ProfileCommon isn't supported. At the same time, there isn't really a clear migration path.

Comment: Please show some code or something. What on earth is `ProfileCommon`?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov ProfileCommon is a auto generated file on asp.net website projects, includes you custom properties as well. Since he moved to MVC it is now a web application project and hence he is not seeing this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web application projects don't auto generate that file, check out http://weblogs.asp.net/joewrobel/archive/2008/02/03/web-profile-builder-for-web-application-projects.aspx and http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WebProfileBuilder.